# PHP - Can write to file, but not read

Tags: php, io

I have a PHP script, which attempts to read a file and output it, but none of the ways I know are working. It's kind of a weird case, since I can WRITE to the file, but not read it.

Posting any code would probably be unnecessary, I simply tried reading the file, first with `file_get_contents`, and then with `fopen`. None of them rises an error, they simply return an empty string. Even `filesize` returns 0 as the length. The only thing, that works is `filemtime`.

Any ideas why writing would be possible, but not reading?

**EDIT:**

It seems like file_get_contents works, when I point to the file, directly, using FTP, although a **new weird issue** came up: before the while-loop in my original code, it does return the file's text, but IN the while loop, it doesn't. And it's printing anything else with no problem, so it's not an echo-related issue..

Comment: Please post code. It's necessary.

Comment: Well, I was absolutely serious about the code. At the moment I saw my code isn't working, I made a new test PHP script, trying just: echo file_get_contents('filename'); and it didn't work as well.

Comment: So your file is called `filename` and is in the current working directory of your script

Comment: Do `var_dump(is_file('filename'))` right before your `file_get_contents` call. Good chance you have a path issue.

Comment: Well, it's called 't', actually and it is the same directory of the script.

Comment: @jszobody, I check the existamce of the file and if it's readable with is_readable, but the functions both returns FALSE.

Comment: Please post code. It's necessary.